# How prove this $|z|>1$ with $1+z+\frac{z^2}{2!}+\cdots+\frac{z^n}{n!}=0$

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality

For give the  postive integer $n$,and  $z\in C$ such this

> $$1+z+\dfrac{z^2}{2!}+\cdots+\dfrac{z^n}{n!}=0$$
>
> show that $$|z|> 1$$

maybe we Assmue that exst $z$ such
$$|z|\le 1$$
then we have
$$z(1+\dfrac{z}{2}+\cdots+\dfrac{z^{n-1}}{n!})=-1$$

so
$$|z|\cdot\left|1+\dfrac{z}{2}+\cdots+\dfrac{z^{n-1}}{n!}\right|=1$$
then we have
$$\left|\dfrac{z}{2}+\cdots+\dfrac{z^{n-1}}{n!}\right|\ge 1$$
then I can't have idea

Comment: Please ask your question more clearly. Are you trying to prove that any solution of the polynomial equation must satisfy $|z| > 1$?

Comment: What about $z=-1$ for $n=1$?

Comment: no,n is give it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, for $n = 1$, the zero is $z = -1$. For $n > 1$, consider

\begin{align}
(1-z)\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{z^k}{k!} &= \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{z^k}{k!} - \sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \frac{z^k}{(k-1)!}\\
&= 1 + \sum_{k=1}^n \left(\frac{1}{k!} - \frac{1}{(k-1)!}\right)z^k - \frac{z^{n+1}}{n!}.
\end{align}

For $\lvert z\rvert \leqslant 1$, we therefore have

$$\left\lvert (1-z)\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{z^k}{k!}\right\rvert \geqslant 1 - \sum_{k=2}^n \left(\frac{1}{(k-1)!} - \frac{1}{k!}\right) - \frac{1}{n!} = 0,$$

and the inequality is strict for $z \neq 1$. But it is evident that

$$\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1^k}{k!} > 0.$$